# Map DATA to jqGrid

Tags: jquery, hashmap, jqgrid

how to send data as a Map to jqGrid ?

backend:

```
    List<Map<String, Object>> rows = new ArrayList<>();

    Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    data.put("code", "ONE");
    data.put("libelle", "ONELibelle");
    data.put("titre", "ONEValeurCarac");
    Map<String, Object> data2 = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    data2.put("code", "ONE2");
    data2.put("libelle", "iONELibelle2");
    data2.put("titre", "ONEValeurCarac2");
    Map<String, Object> data3 = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    data3.put("code", "ONE3");
    data3.put("libelle", "ONELibelle3");
    data3.put("titre", "ONEValeurCarac3");
    rows.add(data);
    rows.add(data2);
    rows.add(data3);
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String datajson = gson.toJson(rows);
```

i send the variable datajson as data, in receive (varColModel : code,libelle,titre)

```
var myGrid = $("#jqGrid").jqGrid({
        url : myurl,
        datatype : "json",
        mtype : 'POST',
        colModel : varColModel,
        headertitles : true,
        rowNum : 50,
        scrollOffset:50,
        sortname : 'code',
        sortorder : 'asc',
```

the grid is empty.

Answer (score 0):

colModel can  not be changed after it is created.
One possible solution is to have all the possible columns and then show/hide certain by condition.

You can put here server response and grid config in order to look what is wrong